# Automatic linebreak in footer with \pagestyle{fancy}

Tags: header-footer, line-breaking

I have created my footer as follows:

```
\fancyfoot[L]{\textcolor{grey}{\sffamily{\footnotesize{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}}} % Fuß links
\fancyfoot[C]{\sffamily{\thepage}}                                                 % Fuß mitte
\fancyfoot[R]{\textcolor{grey}{\sffamily{\footnotesize{\autor}}}}                  % Fuß rechts

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}                                % Liniendicke Fuß
```

When my chapter name is too long, the left part of my footer overlaps into my page numbers.

[image: <code>\fancyfoot[L]</code> is overlapping]

How can I prevent the overlapping? Is it possible to autobreak the chaptername/shorten it once it is too long?

Comment: try `\fancyfoot[L]{\parbox[t]{0.4\linewidth}{\textcolor{grey}{\sffamily{\footnotesize{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}}}}` if this is what you looking for. This will also influence on space reserved for footer. Wlecome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fro break long text in footer into more line you need to enclose it to `\parbox` with prescribed width, for example `0.45\linewidth`:

```
\fancyfoot[L]{\parbox[t]{0.4\linewidth}{
    \textcolor{grey}{\sffamily\footnotesize\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}}   % Fuß links
\fancyfoot[C]{\sffamily\thepage}                                        % Fuß mitte
\fancyfoot[R]{\textcolor{grey}{\sffamily\footnotesize{\autor}}}         % Fuß rechts

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

Note: multi line text will influence on space reserved for footer.

Comment: You could \smash the \parbox.  The baseline won't change.